# Adding terms to a document

Tags: web-services, taxonomy

I want to use Web services to add Terms to a document in Sharepoint.
I have already explored the `TaxonomyClientService` but it doesnt have any ways in which I can attach terms to a document.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working by following this example - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sridhara/archive/2010/07/09/update-taxonomy-field-values-in-a-list-item-through-sharepoint-web-services.aspx

Tina